# NullPointerException when trying to set value based on column data type

Tags: java, mysql, sql, nullpointerexception

So I am currently learning a little about java and sql, using MySQL. I wrote a function to insert a new row into a table using a prepared statement. I created an array for the values I want to put in so I can loop over them. Since the columns have differing datatypes, I tried using the getMetaData().getColumnTypeName() method to use the appropriate function for the datatype, but it just gives me a null pointer exception.

I tried using the same approach in a regular statement using ResultSet and it worked just fine. Here is my function:

```
public void insertCustomer() {
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customers(customerNumber, customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName," +
                " phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postalCode, country, " +
                " creditLimit) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        String[] columns = {"customerNumber(int)", "customerName(String)", "contactLastName(String)",
                "contactFirstName(String)", "phone(String)", "addressLine1(String)", "addressLine2(String)",
                "city(String)", "state(String)", "postalCode(String)", "country(String)", "creditLimit(double)"};

        String[] values = new String[12];

        for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter " + columns[i] + ": ");
            values[i] = input.nextLine();

            /* Gives NullPointerException
            if(ps.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i + 1).equals("INT"))
                ps.setInt(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(values[i]));

            if(ps.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i + 1).equals("VARCHAR"))
                ps.setString(i + 1, values[i]);

            if(ps.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i + 1).equals("DOUBLE"))
                ps.setDouble(i + 1, Double.parseDouble(values[i]));*/
        }

        ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        ps.setDouble(12, Double.parseDouble(values[11]));

        for(int i = 1; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
            ps.setString(i + 1, values[i]);
        }

        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I commented out the code giving me the exception. They should replace the 5 lines of code below the if statements.

Again, Im really new to SQL and Java so keep that in mind :)

Comment: Since you're getting an NPE, what you do in this situation is look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getMetaData()) of the method that's returning `null` to find out why it's returning `null`. The documentation in this case says *"...or `null` if the driver cannot return a ResultSetMetaData` object"*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder jdk-14 will come with a JEP that will simplify this NPE; at least understanding them will be _a lot_ easier.

Comment: use connection string like following  : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true

Comment: @VolkanAlbayrak doesnt work

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know the problem has to do with the index, but not how to fix it.